# Referencing a pointer of int arrays

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I need to populate an array of integer arrays(with the size of four). I have the following piece of code where I populate pointsList in another project and use the populated pointsList to write data into a file in main method,

```
main(){
    int** pointsList = new int*[5000];
    meshmodel(pointsList);
    //do something with pointsList  
}

meshmodel(int** &(pointsList)){ //this method is in another project

    for(int j = 0; j<5000; j++){
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
            pointsList[j] = new int[4];
            pointsList[j][i] = id;

        }

    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the populated pointsList isn't actually populated correctly, 
 ex - in pointsList[0] array only pointsList[0][3] is populated correctly all others have null/memory location values in them.

How can I populate pointsList correctly. I am unable to pass vectors due to differences between projects.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want `pointsList[j] = new int[4];` outside of the inner loop.

Comment: As is you're leaking all but the last assignment to `pointsList[j]` with each inner iteration.

Comment: Jeez, thanks... I feel like a fool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop is a little off.

Change it to:

```
for(int j = 0; j<5000; j++){
    pointsList[j] = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        pointsList[j][i] = id;
    }
}
```

You were allocating 4 times and were keeping the last one.